# Need help i’m working on a turtelbot project

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
first of all excuse my bad english, i don't if i'm in the good section or no.
I'm working on a turtlebot 2 project.
my subject is to make a PID controller of the robot to control each wheel
i started with a trajectory pathing where i estimate the error
after that, i managed to find the expression of the velocity ( angular and linear ) from the errors
now i am modeling the dynamical of the robot but **i need a connexion between the velocities and the torque of the wheels ( left and right ) if its possible**
because i can't find other way to model it
i'm working with simulink to do my project and after i will implant it directlly in the turtlebot 2
and also if anyone of you had ever worked with a similar project i'll be greatful if he share his knowledge with me
Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250896/need-help-i%E2%80%99m-working-on-a-turtelbot-project/) by [driss.aourir@gmail.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/28912/driss.aourir@gmail.com/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-12-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kartikmadhira1](https://answers.ros.org/users/28274/kartikmadhira1/) on 2016-12-29**:
Can be more specific as to why you need torque and velocity relation?

**Comment by [driss.aourir@gmail.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/28912/driss.aourir@gmail.com/) on 2016-12-29**:
i need the torques for the dynamical model of the robot in the out of the PID controller i have [v w]' the velocities.
so i need some relation to deduce torques expressions and then in my dynamical model outputs i'll get [ x y theta]'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't think anyone has a dynamics model of the turtlebot 2; most projects use simple PID controllers and tune them experimentally until they provide decent results.

If you really need the system model, I suggest you gather the data and model the system yourself. In my experience, the two hardest parts of designing a good controller are capturing the system model, and doing the mathematics to verify the controller.

As an aside, I haven't heard of many people building controllers that control the torque or PWM applied to the turtlebot wheels (most people send velocities and use the built-in controller). You may want to make sure that you can actually send the control signal that you think you can send before you put a bunch of effort into building a controller that outupts torque values.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-12-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0